# How to use full GPU acceleration in opencv python project?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, yolov4, python

I have built opencv-4.5.3 from source with CUDA, fast math, dnn using cmake. Also added CUDA backend and target to use acceleration.

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("./yolov4.cfg", "./yolov4_last.weights")
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)
```

I am using Nvidia rtx 3060. Still getting slow streaming from RTSP. Is there any way to use full gpu memory for a single python project?

Answer (score 0):

Opencv does not use GPU for image decoding by default, even if you built it from source with CUDA flags. You can use gstream for that with:

```
import cv2
pipeline = "rtspsrc location=\"rtsp://login:password@host:port/\" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGRx! videoconvert ! appsink"
capture = cv2.VideoCaputure(pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

Check first, if your built cv2 with gstreamer capabilities by:

```
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())
```

Also, check you camera firmware updates and stream channels, and additional configurations that may be slowing down or delaying the camera stream.

Comment: I have rebuilt opencv from source after installing Gstreamer. But after that it shows me this error which I can't solve.  
import cv2
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.